# Jenkins Auto update

Tags: github, jenkins, redgate

I have a question, Im trying to commit updates that im doing on my database to a Github, I am using redgate to setup the repository and commit the changes.

Anyway I am trying to connect Github repo to Jenkins, so whenever I commit change.

So the trigger is update one the repo, what I want is to get changes on the repo without pressing 'BUILD NOW' on Jenkins.

I already installed github plugin to Jenkins and but in the new version there is no trigger ' Build when a change is pushed to Github'.

Also I tried Web-hook but I am not really familiar with it.

Any hint or idea that might help! 
and I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

**GitHub Jenkins Trigger**

On the new [release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/releases/tag/v1.25.1) of the GitHub plugin, trigger `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` has been renamed to `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling`. So choose this instead.

**GitHub Webhook**

There is a quick and good guide [here](https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/jenkins/github/2015/04/17/github-jenkins/) about creating a webhook on GitHub and link it to your Jenkins build.

In short in GitHub navigate to :

Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Service -> Add Services -> "Jenkins (GitHub plugin)"

Then

> Enter your webhook URL in the “Jenkins hook URL” field and press “Add
>   service”

[image: github plugin]

To test that everything has been configured correctly:

> click on the created service and
>   press the “Test service” button in the upper right corner. If
>   everything is correctly configured, the Jenkins service has got a
>   green checkmark icon in the service overview and the build process has
>   started.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no trigger for

```
' Build when a change is pushed to Github'.
```

Then simply downgrade the plugin version and try again.